# HTML form submit not calling Javascript "onsubmit" handler in Wordpress post

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms

I have a basic HTML form with a submit button at the end. Problem is, the Javascript function I have provided as "onsubmit" handler in the form header is not being called.

```
<form name="Details" method="post" onsubmit="validateForm()" id="Details_Form_ID">
```

This handler function is defined in the same file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    alert('I am an alert box!');
}
</script>
```

When I look at code in Chrome tools, I notice that the above Javascript code itself is wrapped under a `<p>` element and not shown as a "script"...screenshot below. I suspect that the Javascript is being treated as plain text and hence not executing.

[image]

How do I overcome this? I am using wordpress and have edited a "post" to include this code.

Comment: In my case the issue was that Ajax form handler not being called after form submit. Instead it would directly branch to the 'action' parameter given in the form.

The basic issue was due to repeated switching of WYSIWYG and HTML editors in the wordpress, somehow the ajax form submit handler was commented out by automatically by inserting ![CDATA[.

The solution is to disable WYSIWYG while editing wordpress posts and delete the ![CDATA[ keyword before the scripts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the issue was that Ajax form handler not being called after form submit. Instead it would directly branch to the 'action' parameter given in the form. The basic issue was due to repeated switching of WYSIWYG and HTML editors in the wordpress, somehow the ajax form submit handler was commented out by automatically by inserting ![CDATA[.

The solution is to disable WYSIWYG while editing wordpress posts and delete the ![CDATA[ keyword before the scripts..

Answer (score 2):

may be it is calling it but page get refreshed try preventing defualt action and than check if alert gets called?

```
    onsubmit="validateForm(); return false;"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried it but preventDefault() does not help either. The problem I feel is somewhere else. Its not even recognizing the script itself so cannot execute.